# Entity Framework query is loading child properties into another variable. Why?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core (7) I have the following entities:

```
public class Person {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
  public Int32 PersonId { get; set; }
  public String City { get; set; }
}
```

Then I ran the following queries with a break point on the second line.

```
List<Context.Person> a = context.Persons.ToList();

List<Context.Person> b = context.Persons.Include(x => x.Address).ToList();
```

When I check the variable "a" the Address in each list item is null which makes sense because I am not including Address in the first query.

Then I allow the second query to run and I see that the Address in "b" list items have an Address different from null which also makes sense because I am including it.

What is strange is that after I run "b" the Address in "a" items is loaded.

Why? Can I avoid this?

I am creating a few tests and this is a behavior I would like to avoid.

Comment: the problem is your context is getting bigger as you include the adresses, and therefore the a.Address property is filled as well. try adding the adresses in a different context - maybe disabling lazy loading might help as well

Comment: Lazy Loading does not exist in Entity Framework Core ... Is there any other way of solving this without using 2 contexts? My lists have only 8 records and each one 1 address. I find it strange that is doing this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why?

Because by default queries that return entity types are [Tracking queries](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/tracking.html#tracking-queries), which means the `Person` object instances in your case are shared between the two calls by the same context. And because they are reference types, the loaded information by the later query is also visible in the result of the former.

> Can I avoid this?

You can use [No-tracking queries](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/tracking.html#id2):

```
var a = context.Persons.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```